# How to get the sum of adding two Pairs in scala?

Tags: scala, list, tuples

I need to find out how I can take two Pairs and get the sum of each value when adding them together. So let's say I have two pairs:

```
(1,2) and (3,4), I want to get the sum of them which would be (4,6) - (1+3, 2+4).
```

The next part of this is that I have two lists of pairs, and I want to get the sum of each pair in these lists. Each list will have the same number of pairs. So for example:

```
List((1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2))
List((3,4), (3,4), (3,4), (3,4))

res: List((4,6), (4,6), (4,6), (4,6))
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having with your solution?

Comment: I saw some suggestions online that were along the lines of: for ( (a,b) <- l1(l2, 0, 0)) yield (a,b) but it just added the second pair to the end of the first, so the list would be List((1,2)(3,4),(1,2)(3,4),(1,2)(3,4),(1,2)(3,4))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `zip`:

```
List((1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2)).zip(List((3,4), (3,4), (3,4), (3,4))).map {
  case ((a1,b1), (a2,b2)) => (a1+a2, b1+b2)
}
```

which yields: `List((4,6), (4,6), (4,6), (4,6))`.